# React useState and useEffect state is behind by one step

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm aware that updates to state are asynchronous and batched for performance reasons. Knowing that I chose to use useState() and useEffect() to wait for my state to update and then act on it.  The problem I have is that my state is always one step behind what it should be.

```
const myFunctionalComponent: React.FC<Props> = (
  props: Props
) {
  const [lastRequestURL, setLastRequestURL] = useState<string>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (lastRequestURL !== undefined) {
      (async () => {
        try {
          await webRequest(lastRequestURL);
        } catch (e) {
          setResponse(undefined);
        }
      })();
    }
  }, [lastRequestURL]);

 const webRequest = async (value: string) => {
  const response = await axios.get(createURL(`/myServer/website-to-query?url=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`);
  // I do operations server-side with value (a URL) and then send a response back
  if (response) {
    if (newResponse.data.URL &&
              lastRequestURL !== newResponse.data.URL) { // I send the URL back in the data
      return; // This guard check is the key functionality that I want to work. 
      // I check the URL that was used for the request vs. the most recent 
      // URL that a handle change call has received. If it is not the same, 
      // that means that I've don't want to display anything as that 
      // info from the server is already invalid with the front-end's new state
    }
    // Do stuff that is valid for the front-end b/c we passed the check
  }
}

const handleChange = async (value: string): Promise<void> => {
    setLastRequestURL(value);
};
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: why are you trying to access the state directly inside webRequest? you're already passing it as a parameter

Comment: Yes, react state updates *are* asynchronous, but they ***are not*** `async` functions, you can't await them to be processed. React state is considered constant within a render cycle, which includes the entirety of the `useEffect` hook callback. It closes over the state value from the render cycle it was invoked in.

Comment: @diedu There can be more than one call to handleChange before webRequest resolves with the desired data. Thus, using the URL is akin to using sequence numbers for multiple HTTP requests and throwing out responses that were from requests that preceded the corresponding request of a response that we already got.

Comment: @DrewReese Is there a way that I can do this without moving webRequest into the useEffect callback? I actually have helpers from the libraries that I call in webRequest so I'm not even sure that that as a last-resort bad solution would work? Would it help if I made this a class component?

Comment: Do what? What are you trying to do? I'm guessing somewhere in the effect hook callback you are calling `setLastRequestURL` and expecting `lastRequestURL` to somehow update within the same function?

Comment: @DrewReese I'm not, I want setLastRequestURL to maintain its value when accessed a posteriori from webRequest. As of now when I ask for setLastRequestURL it does not have the updated value that is has inside of useEffect. I'm going to edit my example code to show that.

Comment: it really seems like you're tangling yourself with react lifecycle instead of doing it in some other way, are you trying to implement some kind of queue? why not call the `webRequest` from `handleChange`?

Comment: you are seeing that `undefined` because that's the value of the state when webRequest is created, you can google "javascript closure" to understand it better

Comment: First and foremost, thanks to both of you. I don't have much experience with React so it's been tough. @diedu Without React I don't think it's a hard problem to solve; you have a shared memory location that all webRequest calls can access and overwrite, and that's easy. The problem is my lack of knowledge of React. The thing is is that if I call it from one handleChange call then I need other handleChange calls to share memory with the prior call so that they can overwrite the lastRequestURL. Could I use a global variable here outside all of the React stuff? Would that work?

Comment: Perhaps instead of us trying to explain react component lifecycle and playing 20 questions you could just update your question to include the *actual* relevant code that is causing you issue. As-is, it isn't clear what your code does, or what your objective is, and without the other component code we can't dig deeper to help you. If you could share a *running* codesandbox that reproduces your issue that would be sublime; we could live debug it.

Comment: no idea what you want to accomplish hehe but it sounds like something that redux or any other state container could solve, there is a learning curve you'll go throught but it is worth if you'll be continue working with react

Comment: @DrewReese Unfortunately the code is proprietary and thus I don't have that liberty. In my third comment to this question responding to I explain the purpose. I've changed my code a lot  in my original question above to give you a better illustration of what's happening (without inserting everything from my actual code). If checking the URL is confusing, just imagine it as a timestamp. I know it's confusing but I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Your useEffect should always declare dependencies that are not static - `useEffect(() => { ... }, [lastRequestURL])`

Comment: @Dominic Sorry, I had that in my original code but just forgot it when writing it on StackOverflow. Fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: So as @diedu points out in the first comment, you are already passing the state `lastRequestURL` to `webRequest` as `value`... why not continue referencing it later in `lastRequestURL !== newResponse.data.URL` as `value !== newResponse.data.URL`? I guess there still isn't enough code to know what and when `lastRequestURL` isn't what you think it should be. It doesn't have to be a copy/paste of your proprietary code, a reasonable reproducible facsimile is sufficient.

Comment: @DrewReese The reason why I can't reference it as value is because that would just evaluate to true every time. The reason the guard is there is because I can have multiple handleChange calls within milliseconds of each other and every time it happens I want set lastRequestURL so that I know what my most recent handleChange wanted. When a network response comes back a few seconds later, it won't necessarily be in order. The guard allows to me to just focus on the most recent handleChange response and use that. Thank you so much for the help; I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**: I don't think this would be a good practice but if you really need it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯, you can also take a look to axios's request [cancelation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation)

You can use a `ref` to store a mutable variable, so it would be independent of react lifecycle

```
const myFunctionalComponent: React.FC<Props> = (
  props: Props
) {
  const lastRequestURL = useRef<string>(undefined);

  const webRequest = async (value: string) => {
    const response = await axios.get(createURL(`/myServer/website-to-query?url=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`);
    // I do operations server-side with value (a URL) and then send a response back
    if (response) {
      if (newResponse.data.URL &&
                lastRequestURL.current !== newResponse.data.URL) { // I send the URL back in the data
        return; // This guard check is the key functionality that I want to work. 
        // I check the URL that was used for the request vs. the most recent 
        // URL that a handle change call has received. If it is not the same, 
        // that means that I've don't want to display anything as that 
        // info from the server is already invalid with the front-end's new state
      }
      // Do stuff that is valid for the front-end b/c we passed the check
    }
  }

  const handleChange = async (value: string): Promise<void> => {
    await webRequest(value);
    lastRequestURL.current = value;
  };
}
```

https://www.emgoto.com/storing-values-with-useref/

Comment: @hotzjacobb notice that I removed the `useEffect` since I think is unnecessary, if you keep it you'd always need a state to pass the current url request and the ref to track the last url, let me know if you really need it that way to update my answer

Comment: Thanks, no, I don't think I need it. Would using useRef be better practice than just using and mutating a variable declared outside of my functional component?

Comment: @hotzjacobb there is an explanation to that in the link I added at the end